# How to teach SpecFlow to add additional NUnit attributes to my test class

Tags: nunit, specflow, class-attributes

[SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org) is great - and it helps us very much to do proper integration testing.

One thing I was wondering is whether there's a way to tell SpecFlow to add additional NUnit attributes to the test class it creates in the feature code-behind file.

Right now, my test class gets generated something like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "1.8.1.0")]
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute()]
[NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("Some action description here")]
public partial class MySampleFeature
{  
   ......
}
```

Is there any way in SpecFlow to tell it to add an additional NUnit attribute to define the category of the test - like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "1.8.1.0")]
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute()]
[NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("Some action description here")]
[NUnit.Framework.Category("LongRunningTests")]   <== add this "Category" attribute
public partial class MySampleFeature
{  
   ......
}
```

Adding this manually to the generated code-behind is wasteful - next time SpecFlow re-generates that code-behind, I have to remember doing it again (and chances are, I'll forget).

And if that capability is not yet present in SpecFlow - how to petition for this to be added? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact the `NUnit.Framework.Category` attribute is already supported if you use [tags (look for the tags section)](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow) on your feature or scenarios. So if you write

```
@LongRunningTests
Feature: MySampleFeature
```

it will generate the proper `Category` attribute.

However if you want to have additional custom attributes you need to write a custom generator provider with implementing the `IUnitTestGeneratorProvider` interface and register with the [unitTestProvider](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Configuration)'s `generatorProvider` attribute in your config's specflow section.

You can find the source of the built in implementations at [github](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/tree/master/Generator/UnitTestProvider).

Comment: This does not look to be possible in SpecFlow 1.9 because the IUnitTestGeneratorProvider interface is not accessible.  The documentation states that Providers will be replaced with Plugins in v.2.0 when it is released. For example, I would like to implement a custom xUnitGeneratorProvider so that Tags are pushed out to xUnit.NET Traits.

Comment: This is possible in SpecFlow 1.9. You need to create a new project that will host your SpecFlow plugin. In this project, install the SpecFlow NuGet package and the SpecFlow.Plugins NuGet package. The SpecFlow.Plugins NuGet package contains assemblies that allow you to create SpecFlow plugins; and in one of those assemblies is the `IUnitTestGeneratorProvider` and `IUnitTestGeneratorPlugin` interfaces (and I believe a base-class implementation of each).

Answer (score 3):

To add to @nemesv's good answer, once you've added:

@LongRunningTests
Feature: MySampleFeature

To execute from the console, do this:

nunit3-console.exe myTests.dll --where "cat==LongRunningTests"