# DataSource attribute with Specflow for multiple browser testing

Tags: c#, selenium, browser, mstest, specflow

I have some web ui tests in C# which are executed through selenium in browserstack. Currently these are just simple unit ms tests and they are executed againts different browsers. 
I want to port the test to specflow, but I don't really know how to do the multiple browser testing bit.

At the moment, to execute these tests in multiple browsers I am using a [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx) attribute, which basically takes different inputs for the same tests from an XML file

```
[TestMethod]
[Ignore]
[DeploymentItem("JLL.Specs\\Browsers.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\Browsers.xml", "Row", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void LoadHomePageAndFindSearchBox()
{    
   ...
}
```

The problem is that Specflow doesn't support the DataSource attribute. 
Any idea?

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rows>
  <Row>
    <browser>Firefox</browser>
    <browser_version>31.0</browser_version>
    <os>Windows</os>
    <os_version>7</os_version>
    <resolution>1280x1024</resolution>
    <browserName></browserName>
    <platform></platform>
    <device></device>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <browser>Chrome</browser>
    <browser_version>36.0</browser_version>
    <os>Windows</os>
    <os_version>XP</os_version>
    <resolution>1024x768</resolution>
    <browserName></browserName>
    <platform></platform>
    <device></device>
  </Row>

...
```

Comment: Best I could find is this:  http://www.specflow.org/plus/excel/getting-started/  I'm not sure if that's the answer you're looking for though.

Comment: In a single test run, do you want to run all the Scenarios against all browsers?

Comment: At the root of it, SpecFlow just generates unit tests that happen to use the SpecFlow API. I wonder if you could create a custom test generator that adds the appropriate attributes above the test methods. [This StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009181/how-to-teach-specflow-to-add-additional-nunit-attributes-to-my-test-class) talks about creating custom attributes on NUnit tests in SpecFlow. I'm sure the same pattern applies to MS Tests generated by SpecFlow as well.

Comment: Did my answer help? What did you end up doing?

Comment: I am not working with this project any more and I don't access to it, so I can't really check if this works, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a web driver abstraction framework to write driver agnostic test code. To do this I've used [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu). Using this library you can easily switch between different web drivers (e.g. Selenium, Phantom JS, WaitN) without needing to write different driver code.

In a web driver factory class you could then use code like (see [here](https://github.com/featurist/coypu#driver) for more information):

```
sessionConfiguration.Driver = Type.GetType("Coypu.Drivers.Selenium.SeleniumWebDriver, Coypu");
sessionConfiguration.Browser = Drivers.Browser.Parse("firefox");
```

to get an instance of Selenium for FireFox or you could replace "firefox" with "chrome" to get an instance of Chrome.

I've used this approach to run a suite of tests for different browsers and it worked well. However this has meant executing a suite of tests for one browser, and then upon completion running them for another.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use `Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit dll`.

see the Example:

```
@Browser:IE

@Browser:Chrome

@Browser:Firefox
```

Scenario Outline: Add Two Numbers

You can use `@Browser:..........` in your feature file. This attribute will list 3 tests in your test explorer for each browser and you can run whichever you wanted to use.

For detailed information , go [here](https://github.com/baseclass/Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit).

Comment: @asier, please update if your problem has been solved.